# Freeze columns in JXTable

Tags: java, swing, jxtable

I'd like to be able to freeze columns in JXTable just like in Excel spreadsheet and came across this project: [xframe-swing's JXTable](http://xframe.sourceforge.net/swing/jxtable.html).

Just wondering if there is a tutorial for this project. Note that this is not the same as JXTable in swingx project.

Or perhaps there is another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the [Fixed Column Table](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/fixed-column-table/) will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks camickr, I'll give this one a try. It looks promising.